# Select query in Microsoft Access looking up records in another table returning incorrect results

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a database with the following fields: Employee_Manager, and Manager_Department in a table called Employees. I also have a master list of managers with their corresponding departments in a table called Managers with fields named Manager_ID and Department. I am writing a VBA script that will validate whether the employee's manager listed in the employees table is valid - present in the master list of managers. VBA code that I am using is below:

```
Public sub validateManagers(manager as string, managerDepartment as String)

dim db As DAO.database
dim rs As DAO.recordset
dim sqlString as String
set db = currentDb

sqlString = "SELECT [Manager_ID] FROM [Managers] WHERE [Manager_ID] LIKE ""*" & manager & "*"" And [Department] LIKE ""*" & managerDepartment & "*"""

set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString)

if Not rs.EOF Then
    If (Instr(1, rs.Fields(0), manager, vbTextCompare)) <> 0 Then
        validateManagers = "Valid Manager"
    Else
        validateManagers = manager & "Is not a valid manager in" & managerDepartment
    End if
Else
    validateManager = "No matching roles found"
End if
```

Right now the code is only partially working. I have no problems when all the managers in the employees table is found in the Manager table. The code fails however when a manager listed in the employees table does not match the role specified for that manager in the Managers table. **The else clause in the inner if statement does not run as I expect the code to.** Instead the function returns the value in the outer else clause of the outer if statement.

All fields are of type string and there are no trailing / leading spaces in any field value. The VBA compiles fine, just that query is returning incorrect results. The code reaches EOF and returns that "No matching roles found"

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you first step through your code and inspect the values being used to evaluate the IF's. The data might not be what you expect. Note that you could also move this 'IF' into the query which might make it more obvious whats going on (as you can run the query directly in MS Access)

Comment: Why isn't there the `Then` for the second `If` Does it even compile?

Comment: @cha Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your answer, then a tip:

- Your SQL is limiting by manager ID and department
- A manager could have one or many departments, but that doesn't matter here
- What matters is if the SQL returns any records at all, it is guaranteed that your manager and department will be in the results.
- BUT, the way you have it set up, if no results are returned, you can't tell if the manager ID is wrong, or the department. All you know it that the *combination* is invalid.

Recommendations:

Remove the nested If (your InStr test duplicates the SQL Like, and adds no additional specificity):

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
    validateManagers = "Valid Manager and Department"
Else
    validateManagers = manager & " is not a valid manager in " & managerDepartment
End if
```

This logic now matches the SQL.

But, this may not be what you *want*. If you want to validate the existence of the Manager or Department separately, you will need to write separate tests.

Now for the tip:

```
set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString)
```

This code opens your recordset by default as a DynaSet, which is a read/write cursor that lets you move forwards and backwards. This code doesn't need that, so I suggest using a Forward-Only cursor (read-only, forward-only):

```
set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString, dbOpenForwardOnly)
```

This is lighter-weight, and has the nice property of automatically moving to the first record and setting .EOF, so your first if check will always work as intended.